# Python - insert lines on txt following a sequence without overwriting

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I want to insert the name of a file before each file name obtained through glob.glob, so I can concatenate them through FFMPEG by sorting them into  INTRO+VIDEO+OUTRO, the files have to follow this order:

INSERTED FILE NAME
FILE
INSERTED FILE NAME
INSERTED FILE NAME
FILE
INSERTED FILE NAME
INSERTED FILE NAME
FILE
INSERTED FILE NAME

This is this code I'm using:

```
import glob
open("Lista.txt", 'w').close()
file = open("Lista.txt", "a")
list =glob.glob("*.mp4")
for item in list:
  file.write("%s\n" % item)
file.close()

f = open("Lista.txt", "r")
contents = f.readlines()
f.close()

for x,item in enumerate(list):
    contents.insert(x, "CTA\n")
f = open("Lista.txt", "w")
contents = "".join(contents)
f.write(contents)
print f
f.close()
```

But I obtain the values in the wrong order:

INSERTED FILE NAME
INSERTED FILE NAME
INSERTED FILE NAME
FILE
FILE
FILE

How could I solve this?
EDIT: As pointed out, maybe the issue is being caused by modifying a list that I'm currently using.

Comment: Think about what happens to the indices of existing items when you insert a new item before them. In general, changing a list's length while you're iterating over it is a bad idea.

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a variable like you do. It shadow the buildin function/class `list`. Rename it. Idem for `file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to modify `contents` list. I think if new list is used to get final output, then it will be simple and more readable as below. And as **Zen of Python** states

**Simple is always better than complex.**

1. Consider you got `file_list` as below after doing `glob.glob`.

> file_list = ["a.mp4","b.mp4","c.mp4"]

2. Now you want to add "`INSERTFILE`" before and after every element of `file_list` so that final_list will look like

> final_list = ['INSERTFILE', 'a.mp4', 'INSERTFILE', 'INSERTFILE',
>   'b.mp4', 'INSERTFILE', 'INSERTFILE', 'c.mp4', 'INSERTFILE']

3. This final_list you will write to file.

***Problem summary is how to achieve step 2.***

Below code will get step 2.

**Code (with comments inline:**

```
#File List from glob.glob
file_list = ["a.mp4","b.mp4","c.mp4"]
#File to be added
i = "INSERTFILE"
final_list = []
for x in file_list:
    #Create temp_list
    temp_list = [i,x,i]
    #Extend (not append) to final_list
    final_list.extend(temp_list)
    #Clean temp_list for next iteration
    temp_list = []
print (final_list)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
['INSERTFILE', 'a.mp4', 'INSERTFILE', 'INSERTFILE', 'b.mp4', 'INSERTFILE', 'INSERTFILE', 'c.mp4', 'INSERTFILE']
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! thanks, it's true that I went overboard with the complexity, a simple solution would have been best, it's just that I'm a novice with Python and I couldn't think of a simple solution.